# In Ansible playbook: Using a boolean in `when` clause that might be undefined

Tags: ansible

Ansible tasks can have `when` clauses like this:

```yaml
- name: Conditional output
  debug:
    msg: This is a conditional output
  when: some_var
```

In order to protect about `some_var` being undefined, one can use

```yaml
- name: Conditional output
  debug:
    msg: This is a conditional output
  when: some_var is defined and some_var
```

There also seems to be a variant like this:

```yaml
- name: Conditional output
  debug:
    msg: This is a conditional output
  when: some_var | d() | bool
```

Are these variants the same? What are their advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strict equivalence of your two safe examples would be:

```yaml
when: some_var is defined and some_var | bool
```

vs

```yaml
when: some_var | d() | bool
```

The `bool` filter makes sure the var content is interpreted as a boolean and that, as an example taken from my experience, a string answer to a `vars_prompt` is working as expected (`"true"` => `true`).

`d` is an alias to `default` and is documented in [the official jinja2 documentation for the filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default)

The 2 above are strictly equivalent and will produce the same result on all occasion. But I do prefer the most compact one that I would further enhance for documentation reasons like this:

```yaml
when: some_var | d(false) | bool
```

Answer (score 4):

The second form is less readable than the first, but is more flexible.  It reads as follows:

- Evaluate `some_var` variable.
- Have a default value of blank/None (since `d()` [is shorthand for `default()`](https://serverfault.com/a/1005006)).
- Filter to a boolean ([for truthiness](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-variables)).

The first form reads as follows:

- If `some_var` is defined
- Evaluation of `some_var` (as a Python boolean)

If `some_var` [is truthy or has the potential to be truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/1079354), then the first form could fail if it is not precisely `True` or `False`.